# How to customize tkinter menubar on mac?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, menu

I am trying to build an application with `tkinter`. I am using Mac OS Big Sur and I struggle a little bit with `tkinter` `menus`.

[image]
(How do you do screenshots when you want to see the open menubar Haha)

It is no problem to add menu items to that default mac menubar but I want to delete some useless ones. I saw that you can customize the "Preferences" item with this command.
`root.createcommand('tk::mac::ShowPreferences', showMyPreferencesDialog)`
But I could not find anything else. Is this possible?

Comment: On Linux I create screenshots with tool which has `time` option - so I can set 5 seconds to screenshot and I have time to open menu or move mouse to display popup window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, I don't have enough reputation to place a comment. Answering your subquestion: you can do screenshots by pressing `Cmd+Shift+3` for fullscreen, or `Cmd+Shift+4` for a rectangular selection. If that does not work, you have to check your `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots` setting.

Regarding your menu question, you can always replace the whole menu. Here is [a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menu.htm). Though note, the first menu will always stay the same because it does not belong to the app but the system.

Here is a copy of the tutorial:

```
from Tkinter import *

def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()
   
root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=donothing)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=donothing)

editmenu.add_separator()

editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=donothing)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=donothing)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=donothing)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```